# Live booted Lubuntu on 512 MB of ram on Dell Inspiron 6000, Chromium always crashes when trying to go to a webpage

Tags: lubuntu, dell, chromium, inspiron

Here is the error message...
`Either Chrome ran out of memory or the process for the webpage was terminated for some other reason. To contine, reload or go to another page.`
It keeps happening and I have no idea what to do, I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is a low amount of RAM. Booting Live loads the file system into your memory, so that's going to be using up a bunch of RAM. Then trying to use Google Chrome on top of that will use another big chunk. "Either Chrome ran out of memory..." Most likely it did in fact run out of memory.

Comment: Should I set the persistent memory of the live boot to something higher? I had it set to 2GB do you think if I pushed it up a bit, it would alleviate the problem? And thanks for answering btw.

Comment: Persistence, or as you called it, persistent memory, is when you're booting from a USB disk drive and you want to save what you've done. It basically lets the USB disk drive act as a regular hard disk. Persistence has nothing to do with this. The only solution would be buy more RAM, which I doubt you plan on doing. Using Lubuntu I'd be surprised that you're running out of memory though. Open System Monitor and see how much memory is being used.

Comment: You can make a swap partition or a swap file with the persistence and the live system will use it when it runs out of RAM, but it will be very slow. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: "Memory: 117 MB of 242 MB used" That should be enough to run Chromium, right? Hm.

Comment: It should say "___ out of 512 MB used" since you said you have 512mb of RAM. 512mb is barely enough to get by, anything under is nearly impossible. Double check that you have 512mb installed.

Comment: Ah, I think I only have 248MB of RAM, because that what it says on System Information. I could have sworn that I had 512MB of RAM... I'll check on Windows with Safe Mode and see how much RAM I have.

Comment: Oh my god, this laptop only has 256MB of RAM, no wonder I can't do anything. Thanks for the help guys, I really appreciate it. I'm going to try Linux Mint and Puppy Linux to see if I can get better results.

Comment: No problem, but with 256mb, you're going to need something REALLY minimalist!